# Have you suffered time goes fast in Win10?

Tags: windows, synchronization

I am a Win10 Pro + Insider Preview (WSL2) user.

I don't know when it will start, but when I come back from sleep mode about a month ago, there is a problem that Windows time and Internet time (for example, computer and cell phone time) are not synchronized.

This does not happen on all computers, but only on the desktop. It is not in use or occurs in the same environment on the laptop.

The only difference in hardware is that the CPU is a Ryzen 5 2600 and there is a GPU (Nvidia GTX 760), but I am not sure what caused this.

The software is being developed from WSL2 to NodeJS, but the modules and settings are not much different from this laptop.

If you know how to solve the problem other than reinstalling the OS, please answer.

OS: Win10 Pro 2004 (OS build 19041.330)
CPU: Ryzen 5 2600

Comment: Uhm, what programming language?

Comment: I think this problem is not limited on programming language, but the Windows problem. Anyway, I'm developing with nodeJS and mongoDB

Comment: I was asking to make you aware, that Stack Overflow is for programming problems. Sure, how should you know. You just ignored to take the [tour] when it was offered.